# How to set default value for mat-select with reactive form is used

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray, mat-select

I have used reactive forms for creating a dynamic filter form. I want to set the default value for mat-select. Codes are as follows:

**component.html:**

```
<form [formGroup]="filterForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="to-create" formArrayName="filters">
        <div class="sub-items" *ngFor="let child of filters().controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
.
.
.
            <mat-form-field class="form-field column-select" appearance="outline">
                <mat-select formControlName="columnName">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let column of columnList" [value]="column">
                        {{column}}
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
.
.
.
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**component.ts**

```js
columnList = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4'];

ngOnInit(): void {
  const columnListDefault = this.columnList[0];

  this.filterForm.get('columnName')?.setValue(columnListDefault );
}
```

But it does not work and the default value is empty. I studied some related threads such as:

- [Angular Material: mat-select default value when using reactive forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56187371/angular-material-mat-select-default-value-when-using-reactive-forms)
- [Set default option in mat-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50650790/set-default-option-in-mat-select)

How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you define your filterForm as a `FormGroup`? If so you could try to set the value like this: `this.filterForm.setValue({columnName: this.columnList[0]});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form structure is:

> filterForm (root `FormGroup`) --> filters (`FormArray`) --> index (`FormGroup`) --> columnName (`FormControl`)

Hence your statement to set the default value for `columnName` `FormControl` is incorrect.

---

You have to iterate the `FormGroup` in `filters` `FormArray` in order to assign the value to `columnName` `FormControl`.

To set the value to `columnName` control of **first** `FormGroup` in `filters` `FormArray`:

```js
this.filters().get('0').get('columnName').setValue(columnListDefault);
```

To set the value to `columnName` control of **each** `FormGroup` in `filters` `FormArray`:

```js
for (let index in this.filters().controls) {
  (this.filters().get(index) as FormGroup)
    .get('columnName')
    .setValue(columnListDefault);
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bjbzfz?file=src/app/app.component.ts)